# Can't use UIViewRepresentable based on UIView more than once in the same View

Tags: swiftui, uiviewrepresentable

When I try to place several UIViewRepresentable views to ContentView, it's shown only the last one. Here is the code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
        
    @State var customView = UIView()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                CustomView(view: customView)
                
                CustomView(view: customView)
                    .offset(x: 100, y: 0)
            }
            .navigationTitle("Test UIViewRepresentable")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    Button {
                        makeNewView()
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName: "plus")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private func makeNewView() {
        let path = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
        let layer = CAShapeLayer()
        layer.path = path.cgPath
        layer.fillColor = CGColor(red: 1.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0)
        customView.layer.addSublayer(layer)
    }
}
```

I removed model and viewmodel here to simplify the code.
And here is the UIView representable:

```
struct CustomView: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    var view: UIView
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        return view
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {}
}
```

The second view is shifted down, so the first one is in its place but not shown. What should I do to get both views shown in ContentView?

Comment: I don't think you can add a UIView to the view hierarchy more than once.

Comment: Why you are creating an object of UIView in SwiftUI View ?

Comment: I've cleaned my code here for simplicity, but I need some things that SwiftUI View struct can't provide and UIView can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of creating   `@State var customView = UIView()` in ContentView create this in CustomView and use in ContentView Multiple Times like this

UIViewRepresentable

```
struct CustomView: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    var view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        let path = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
        let layer = CAShapeLayer()
        layer.path = path.cgPath
        layer.fillColor = CGColor(red: 1.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0)
        view.layer.addSublayer(layer)
        return view
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {}
}
```

SwiftUI View

```
struct ContentView: View {
   
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                CustomView()
                
                CustomView()
                    .offset(x: 100, y: 0)
            }
            .navigationTitle("Test UIViewRepresentable")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    Button {
                       // CustomView()
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName: "plus")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

[image]